# How to implement Inline toolbar in react-draft-wysiwyg?

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am making rich text editor in react and want to implement inline toolbar in react-draft-wysiwyg. I surfed all internet to find doc on that but didn't get any. If anyone here have done that in anyway with any package give your valuable answer.

I will post my implementation below :

```
mport React, { Component, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";

import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
// import "./editor.css"

// import '../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';

const MyEditor = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
    
  const onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    console.log(editorState);
    setEditorState(editorState);
  };
  return (
    <Editor
      toolbar={{
        options: ["textAlign", "link", "embedded", "image"],

        inline: { inDropdown: true },
        blockType: {
          inDropdown: true,
        },
        list: { inDropdown: true },
        textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
        link: { inDropdown: false },
      }}
      wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
      editorClassName="editor-class"
      toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
      editorState={editorState}
      onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
    />
  );
};

export default MyEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I second this request. The issue seems to be that although https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/ has an inline toolbar functionality (https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/inline-toolbar), it does not play nicely with react-draft-wysiwyg. The library react-draft-wysiwyg seems to have been all but abandoned, which seems a shame considering even draftjs-utils is still getting over 250k downloads on github alone - and is trending up!!

I expect part of this is because there is a newer version of draft js coming called Lexical by Facebook https://lexical.dev/docs/intro. The whole architecture seems to adopt extensibility better than the original draft js, so perhaps it's worth looking at this as a solution, if that's an option.